# spring RequestHeader annotation on model object?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-3

Can I put @RequestHeader on a model object property? I.e.

```
class MyModel {
    String ua;
    public void setUa(@RequestHeader("User-Agent") String ua) {
        this.ua = ua;
    }
}
```

This works with @RequestParam, but seems to have no effect when I use @RequestHeader. Am I missing something? And, if this isn't supported, is there some reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this only in controller methods. Not model objects. Check [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestheader)

Comment: I figured this much and what I was really wondering was *why*. After all, it's supported for @RequestParam, doesn't @RequestHeader fall into the same general category? Anyway, I'll live. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin - it's not supported for request param afaik.

Comment: I've got code where RequestParam binds to model object bean properties, so I know it works.

Comment: @Kevin Ah, well, binding is the keyword here I guess. It is logical for params to bimd to objects, and not so much about other request parts, like headers. But they couldve implemented it. Actually it shouldnt be hard to write, by looking at the code handling params